# Ruby docusign_esign: unable to use template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use an existing template in Docusign to send an envelope for signing. However, I get a `RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED` error message even though I use template roles to set recipients.

If I try to add signers instead, I get `ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE`, I assume because it's not using the template.

I know the credentials are fine, and I'm able to create a new envelope and add sign-here tabs. But I just can't figure out how to use the template. I tried emulating the `node.js` example here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/request-a-signature-via-email-using-a-template making the code analogous but it didn't work.

```
# Create the envelope request
envelope = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({
  emailSubject: "my subject",   # BTW the documentation seems incorrect on this, it's camel-cased not underscore separated
  template_id: ENV['DS_TEMPLATE_ID'] || "98..........f"
})

role = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
  role_name: 'MyRole', # same string as defined in the template via web gui
  name: DSConfig.signer_name,
  email: DSConfig.signer_email
})

envelope.template_roles = [role];
envelope.status = "sent"

envelope_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new(@@api_client)
result = envelope_api.create_envelope(@@account_id, envelope)
```

Should be creating a new envelope, but gives me:

```
message: {
  "errorCode": "RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED",
  "message": "No recipients were found in the request."
}
```

Hope someone can help, there's not a lot of information on the ruby usage out there.

EDIT: After a lot of experimentation and digging around the gem code, it seems the documentation is incorrect, especially in relation to camelCase vs underscores. Here's code that actually worked. Hope it can help more people!

```
# Create the envelope request
envelope = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({
  emailSubject: "my subject",
  emailBlurb: "Some Text for email body",
  templateId: ENV['DS_TEMPLATE_ID'] || "98..........f"
})
role = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
  roleName: 'MyRole', # same string as defined in the template via web gui
  name: DSConfig.signer_name,
  email: DSConfig.signer_email
})
text = [
  DocuSign_eSign::Text.new({
    tabLabel: 'texttabname', # these should match the template
    name: 'texttabname',
    value: "222.222.222-22"
  })]
tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new
tabs.text_tabs = text
role.tabs = tabs
envelope.template_roles = [role];
envelope.status = "sent"

envelope_api = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new(@@api_client)
result = envelope_api.create_envelope(@@account_id, envelope)
```

And voilà! This actually used the template, sent it to the signer (as his role) and pre-filled the text tabs. Whew! The main difficulty here was that the documentation (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/DocuSign_eSign) is all in underscore separated name, whereas in practice it's camel case. I looked at the REST requests it was generating and figured out that the data wasn't being filled out.

Comment: Glad it's working. And welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your answer as an answer (below). Yes, you can answer your own questions.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for your help in sending the examples in https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant , Larry. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

When using a template it's important to remember there are two types of recipients in templates:
1. Fixed
2. Placeholders.

the first type require no additional work. 
The second type require that you specify the details, email+name, of the recipient before the document can be sent out (even if they are not the first it will be routed to).
In order for DocuSign to match the recipients, we use the roleName which is not a GUID but a text name you call placeholder recipients. It should match exactly how you defined the recipient in the template (while recipientID, the GUID, would be different for the template from the resulting envelope).

Doing that would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue.
i got a solution its working for me.

```
def make_envelope(args)
  signer = DocuSign_eSign::Signer.new(
  email: args[:signer_email], name: args[:signer_name],
  roleName: 'signer', recipientId: '1',
  clientUserId: args[:signer_client_id]
)

text_tabs_fields = {:documentId=>"1", :pageNumber=>"1", :value=>"Satish", :xPosition=>97, :yPosition=>126}
text_tab =DocuSign_eSign::Text.new(text_tabs_fields)


sign_here = DocuSign_eSign::SignHere.new (signature_fields)

tabs = DocuSign_eSign::Tabs.new
tabs.text_tabs = [text_tab]
tabs.sign_here_tabs = [sign_here]
signer.tabs = tabs

recipients_server_template = DocuSign_eSign::Recipients.new(
   'signers' => [signer]
)

comp_template = DocuSign_eSign::CompositeTemplate.new(
  compositeTemplate_id: '1',
  serverTemplates: [DocuSign_eSign::ServerTemplate.new(
    sequence: '1', templateId: args[:template_id]
  )],
  # Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
  inlineTemplates: [
    DocuSign_eSign::InlineTemplate.new(
      'sequence' => '2',
      'recipients' => recipients_server_template
    )
  ]
)

envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new(
  status: 'sent',
  compositeTemplates: [comp_template]
)
envelope_definition
end
```